# Starting a program with the debugger attached causes program shutdown

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll

When i start my C++ program through Visual Studio 2012 with the debugger attached, the program shuts down as soon as the dll loads. The call stack shows that FreeLibrary is being called.

I am running VS in administrator mode, and attaching the debugger after the dll has fully loaded works fine. Attaching the debugger during load causes the same problem.
Starting the program from VS without attaching a debugger also works fine.

This program consists out of a launcher (Game.exe) that loads a dll (hw.dll) that in turns loads the dll i'm trying to debug (client.dll). As soon as the dll loads, the program shuts down, and because the program calls a function pointer initialized after the dll has loaded, it also results in a null pointer call.

Here is the stack trace:

```
00000000()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  
client.dll!AlertMessage(ALERT_TYPE atype, char * szFmt, ...) Line 129   C++
client.dll!MemoryDebug_CheckMemory(const char * pszMoment) Line 122 C++
client.dll!COnShutdownMemoryChecker::~COnShutdownMemoryChecker() Line 424   C++
client.dll!`dynamic atexit destructor for 'g_OnShutdownMemoryChecker''()    C++
client.dll!doexit(int code, int quick, int retcaller) Line 567  C
client.dll!_cexit() Line 408    C
client.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 174 C
client.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 352   C
client.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved) Line 293    C
ntdll.dll!_LdrxCallInitRoutine@16()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine() Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpProcessDetachNode()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpUnloadNode()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrpDecrementNodeLoadCount()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!LdrUnloadDll()    Unknown
KernelBase.dll!_FreeLibrary@4()    Unknown
AcGenral.dll!NS_IgnoreFreeLibrary::APIHook_FreeLibrary(struct HINSTANCE__ *)    Unknown
GameOverlayRenderer.dll!0f57d78d()  Unknown
hw.dll!04a119f6()   Unknown
```

Comment: Try running with http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Have you tried starting the client dll from within a Visual Studio debug session?

Comment: It is trying to tell you that the heap is corrupted.  So badly that the code that displays the message could not complete either and died while trying.

Comment: How can the heap be corrupted simply by attaching a debugger?

Comment: After commenting out all code that uses function pointers received by the dll that loads this dll, i was able to start a debugging session. After that i implemented a DllMain function, and i noticed that the client dll is loaded and unloaded once before being loaded for use. I don't know why this happens, but now that i know why this happens, i can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I have know idea for the reason for the problem above but what about DebugBreak() in the code you want to debug? 
From the stacktrace it seems that the function MemoryDebug_CheckMemory is displaying AlertMessage and then initiats the exit.

Comment: That isn't an answer.